# HTTPS/SSL using square okHTTP lib in public key infrastructure

Tags: android, security, ssl, keystore, okhttp

I need implement whole process of sending data over HTTPS using PKI as described here http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Usage-of-Digital-Certificate.svg

**How to sign (do I really have to do it?) my request with private key, and how to add certificate (which i received from webservice) to it?**

I've my own keystore (http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html (really great blog!)) with webservice RootCA, private key used to create CSR file, and certificate signed by webservice (using csr).

I'm using robospice + square retrofit + square okHttp (or maybe use another HTTP client?) to execute requests and have my own `SSLSocketFactory`:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();  
KeyStore keyStore = App.getInstance().getKeyStoreUtil().getKeyStore();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keyStore);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, AppConfig.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslCtx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
client.setSslSocketFactory(sslCtx.getSocketFactory());
```

Since webservice is not implemented yet, I have no idea if it works, I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me whether I'm going right way or not.

Comment: Check this post : [Does OkHttp support accepting self-signed SSL certs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103174/does-okhttp-support-accepting-self-signed-ssl-certs/24401795#24401795)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code is working, but keep in mind that getting classes from App like `App.getInstance.getKeyStoreUtil()` is not really clean solution