# Android SSL Certificate pinning

Tags: android, ssl

I know there are many questions regarding pinning certificates in Android but I can't find what I am looking for...

I subclass `SSLSocketFactory` and override the `checkServerTrusted()` method. In this method, I do the following:

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(PUB_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8")));
for (X509Certificate cert : chain) {
    // Verifing by public key
    cert.verify(ca.getPublicKey());                      
}
```

One of the items in the chain verifies and the other doesn't (which throws an `Exception`). I guess I can't get a grasp of how certificate chains work.

Should the same public certificate verify with all certificates in the chain?

Comment: Look at the [OWASP site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#Android) for sample code to use with Android.

Comment: You speak of an `Exception`. Any Logcat?

Comment: Are you facing SSLHandshakeException?

Answer (score 2):

### Your Questions and Doubts

> Should the same public certificate verify with all certificates in the chain?

No, because each certificate in the chain (root, intermediate and leaf certificate)) was signed with a different private/public key pair.

> One of the items in the chain verifies and the other doesn't (which throws an Exception). I guess I can't get a grasp of how certificate chains work.

That's because your certificate is the leaf one, thus you can only verify your public key against it, not against the root and intermediate certificate(s).

### A Code Approach

> I subclass SSLSocketFactory and override the checkServerTrusted() method.

If you really want to code it yourself I would suggest you to use instead the built-in OkHttp Ceritficate Pinner, that you can build like this:

```java
import okhttp3.CertificatePinner;

public class OkHttpPinnerService {

    // true if the Approov SDK initialized okay
    private boolean initialized;

    // cached OkHttpClient to use or null if not set
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    public synchronized OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
        if (okHttpClient == null) {
            // build a new OkHttpClient on demand
            if (initialized) {
                // build the pinning configuration
                CertificatePinner.Builder pinBuilder = new CertificatePinner.Builder();
                Map<String, List<String>> pins = YourConfig.getPins("public-key-sha256");
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : pins.entrySet()) {
                    for (String pin : entry.getValue())
                        pinBuilder = pinBuilder.add(entry.getKey(), "sha256/" + pin);
                }

                // build the OkHttpClient with the correct pins preset and ApproovTokenInterceptor
                Log.i(TAG, "Building new Approov OkHttpClient");
                okHttpClient = okHttpBuilder.certificatePinner(pinBuilder.build()).build();
            } else {
                // if the Approov SDK could not be initialized then we can't pin or add Approov tokens
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot build Approov OkHttpClient due to initialization failure");
                okHttpClient = okHttpBuilder.build();
            }
        }

        return okHttpClient;
    }    
}
```

The code was not tested for syntax errors or logical correctness. I just copied it from [this repo](https://github.com/approov/approov-service-okhttp/blob/b4d5a9858601e12869d9a49b17643bc77d122ff6/approov-service/src/main/java/io/approov/service/okhttp/ApproovService.java#L203-L237) and slightly adapted it.

### A Codeless Approach

Since Android API 24 it is possible to implement certificate pinning to the public key hash via the built-in security config file, that doesn't require any code to be written, just a properly configured `network_security_config.xml` file added to your project.

To avoid mistakes while building the `network_security_config.xml` file I recommend you to use the [Mobile Certificate Pinning Generator](https://approov.io/tools/static-pinning/) to extract the live pin being used by the domain you want to pin against and to build for you the correct configuration. For example:

[image: From to add the domains to pin]

[image: Android network security configuration]

Now just copy paste the generated configuration the `network_security_config.xml` file in your project and add this same file to the `AndroifManifest.xml`. Just follow the instructions on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to implement certificate pinning on Android is to use the [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library.

Here is an [excerpt from the documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS#certificate-pinning):

> By default, OkHttp trusts the certificate authorities of the host platform. This strategy maximizes connectivity, but it is subject to certificate authority attacks such as the [2011 DigiNotar attack](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2510951/cybercrime-hacking/hackers-spied-on-300-000-iranians-using-fake-google-certificate.html). It also assumes your HTTPS servers’ certificates are signed by a certificate authority.
>
> Use [CertificatePinner](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.html) to constrain which certificate authorities are trusted. Certificate pinning increases security, but limits your server team’s abilities to update their TLS certificates. **Do not use certificate pinning without the blessing of your server’s TLS administrator!**

```
  public CertificatePinning() {
    client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setCertificatePinner(
        new CertificatePinner.Builder()
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/SXxoaOSEzPC6BgGmxAt/EAcsajw=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/blhOM3W9V/bVQhsWAcLYwPU6n24=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c=")
            .build());
  }

  public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://publicobject.com/robots.txt")
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    for (Certificate certificate : response.handshake().peerCertificates()) {
      System.out.println(CertificatePinner.pin(certificate));
    }
  }
```

And if you need to support a self-signed certificate, the answer to [Does OkHttp support accepting self-signed SSL certs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103174/does-okhttp-support-accepting-self-signed-ssl-certs/24401795#24401795) will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

> Should the same public certificate verify with all certificates in the
>   chain?

Answer:- No.

Most public CAs don't sign server certificates directly. Instead, they use their main CA certificate, referred to as the `root CA`, to sign intermediate CAs. They do this so the root CA can be stored offline to reduce risk of compromise. However, operating systems like Android typically `trust only root CAs` directly, which leaves a short gap of trust between the server certificate—signed by the intermediate CA—and the certificate verifier, which knows the root CA.

> To solve this, the server doesn't send the client only it's
>   certificate during the SSL handshake, but a chain of certificates from
>   the server CA through any intermediates necessary to reach a trusted
>   root CA.

Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#MissingCa) for more information. Hope this will help users.

Answer (score 0):

> Certificate and Public Key Pinning (a.k.a Certificate Pinning) in a
> nutshell -

Normally, an app trusts all pre-installed CAs. If any of these CAs were to issue a fraudulent certificate, the app would be at risk from a man-in-the-middle attack( a.k.a eavesdropping ). Some apps choose to limit the set of certificates they accept by either limiting the set of CAs they trust or by certificate pinning. Certificate pinning is done by providing a set of certificates by hash of the public key. Certificate Pinning is a method that depends on server certificate verification on the client-side.

Below are the 3 ways to implement Certificate Pinning on Android -

- The old-school way - TrustManager - [https://medium.com/@ric…/ssl-pinning-on-android-8baa822e3bd5](https://medium.com/@ric%E2%80%A6/ssl-pinning-on-android-8baa822e3bd5)
- OkHttp CertificatePinner - [https://square.github.io/…/okh…/okhttp3/-certificate-pinner/](https://square.github.io/%E2%80%A6/okh%E2%80%A6/okhttp3/-certificate-pinner/)
- Something fresh - Network Security Configuration - [https://developer.android.com/trai…/articles/security-config](https://developer.android.com/trai%E2%80%A6/articles/security-config)

---

In particular to your question, you could configure the certificates by hash of the public key in NSC using `<pin-set>` tag.

*Note that, when using certificate pinning, you should always include a backup key so that if you are forced to switch to new keys or change CAs (when pinning to a CA certificate or an intermediate of that CA), your app's connectivity is unaffected. Otherwise, you must push out an update to the app to restore connectivity.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <pin-set expiration="2018-01-01">
            <pin digest="SHA-256">7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=</pin>
            <!-- backup pin -->
            <pin digest="SHA-256">fwza0LRMXouZHRC8Ei+4PyuldPDcf3UKgO/04cDM1oE=</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add SSL pinning in a `Kotlin` Android app, follow these step-by-step instructions:
Step 1: Add the OkHttp library to your project.
Add the OkHttp dependency to your app-level `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'
```

Step 2: Create a Certificate Pinning Helper class.
Create a new Kotlin class in your project, e.g., `CertificatePinningHelper`. This class will contain the logic for SSL pinning. Here's a basic implementation:

```
import okhttp3.CertificatePinner
object CertificatePinningHelper {
    private const val HOSTNAME = "your-api-hostname.com"
private const val PIN = "sha256/YourPublicKeyHash"

fun getCertificatePinner(): CertificatePinner {
    return CertificatePinner.Builder()
        .add(HOSTNAME, PIN)
        .build()
}
}
```

Replace your-api-hostname.com with the actual hostname of the API you want to pin certificates for. Replace YourPublicKeyHash with the actual public key hash of the server certificate. You can obtain the public key hash using OpenSSL or other similar tools.

Step 3: Initialize OkHttpClient with CertificatePinner.
In your networking code, create an instance of OkHttpClient and configure it to use the CertificatePinner created in the previous step. Here's an example:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
.certificatePinner(CertificatePinningHelper.getCertificatePinner())
.build()
```

Step 4: Use the OkHttpClient for network requests.
Use the configured OkHttpClient instance for making network requests. For example:

```
import okhttp3.Request
val request = Request.Builder()
.url("https://your-api-hostname.com/api/endpoint")
.build()

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
  override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
    // Handle network request failure
}
    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
   // Handle network response

   }
})
```

Make sure to replace `https://your-api-hostname.com/api/endpoint` with the actual API endpoint you want to access.

That's it! With these steps, you have added SSL pinning to your Kotlin Android app using OkHttp.