# Self-signed certificate for Android Application

Tags: android, security, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I am developing an android application which interacts with my server. For including the SSL layer, I created a self-signed certificate for my server. So, at present when i access my server through a browser, it sends that certificate and once I save it, all works fine on browser.

But I am not sure, how can I move ahead so that my Android app will communicate effectively with the server. The thing I know so far is that I need to generate a keystore (.bks) for my android application and pass it on to TrustManager. I found various tutorials to generate the keystore but I am getting confused at few points:

- Will I need any info regarding the server's certificate for generating this keystore?
- Is there any way through which I can replicate the browser like functionality in the application? (If the certificate is not from a trusted CA, add it to the list if the user confirms that.)
- How will the server trust my keystore?

I might be mixing some of the concepts because I read a lot of articles regarding all this. The articles/questions that I have already referred are:

[Bob Lee's blog](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html)

[Blog on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826045/Android-security-Implementation-of-Self-signed-SSL)

[Using OkHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103174/does-okhttp-support-accepting-self-signed-ssl-certs)

[StackOverflow answer](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-programatically-extract-a-certificate-from-a-site-and-add-it-to-my-keystore)

[Extract cert from server and add to keystore](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-programatically-extract-a-certificate-from-a-site-and-add-it-to-my-keystore)