# OkHttpClient in android is giving 405 Request Method Not Supported error?

Tags: java, android, okhttp, http-status-code-405

I want to send IoT data from an android application to SAP Cloud Platform IoT service. For that, I am using OkhttpClient.
The code used to send request is

```
 private String doGetAsString()
        throws IOException {

    if (connection == null) {
        connect(serverUri);
    }

    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    try {
        Response response = connect(connection);
        String body = response.getBody();

        Console.printText(String.format("Response [%1$d] %2$s", response.getCode(), body));

        return body;
    }
    finally {
        disconnect();
    }
}
```

Code for getting response from the above code is

```
private Response connect(HttpURLConnection connection)
            throws IOException {

        try {
            connection.connect();
        }
        catch (ConnectException e) {
            String errorMessage = "Unable to connect. Please check your Internet connection and proxy settings.";
            throw new IOException(errorMessage, e);
        }

        int code = connection.getResponseCode();

        InputStream stream;
        if (code < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || code >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MULT_CHOICE) {
            stream = connection.getErrorStream();
        }
        else {
            stream = connection.getInputStream();
        }

        String body = null;
        try {
            if (stream == null) {
                body = connection.getResponseMessage();
            }
            else {
                body = readString(stream);
            }
        }
        finally {
            FileUtil.closeStream(stream);
        }

        return new Response(code, body);
    }
```

The value of connection is com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl:https://c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565.eu10.cp.iot.sap/c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565/iot/core/api/v1/tenant/727792470/gateways?filter=protocolId%20eq%20'rest'%20and%20status%20eq%20'online'%20and%20type%20eq%20'cloud'

The serverUri that is passing to the request is [https://c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565.eu10.cp.iot.sap/c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565/iot/core/api/v1/tenant/727792470/gateways?filter=protocolId eq 'rest' and status eq 'online' and type eq 'cloud'](https://c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565.eu10.cp.iot.sap/c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565/iot/core/api/v1/tenant/727792470/gateways?filter=protocolId%20eq%20'rest'%20and%20status%20eq%20'online'%20and%20type%20eq%20'cloud')

But the uri that send from the client seems like https://c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565.eu10.cp.iot.sap/c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565/iot/core/api/v1/tenant/727792470/gateways?filter=protocolId%20eq%20'rest'%20and%20status%20eq%20'online'%20and%20type%20eq%20'cloud'

I get the expected result when coping following url in the browser
https://c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565.eu10.cp.iot.sap/c432c5b0-3ec2-47ad-bf22-23645fa5e565/iot/core/api/v1/tenant/727792470/gateways?filter=protocolId%20eq%20%27rest%27%20and%20status%20eq%20%27online%27%20and%20type%20eq%20%27cloud%27

The authentication is done by username and password

```
 public void connect(String serverUri)
        throws IOException {
    this.serverUri = serverUri;

    connection = openConnection(serverUri);

    if (user != null && password != null) {
        //TODO 2
        byte[] encodedBytes = android.util.Base64.encode((user + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        String base64 = new String(encodedBytes, Constants.DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
    }
    else if (sslSocketFactory != null && connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
        ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    }
    else {
        throw new IOException("No authorization details provided");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This error is about Http Method, are sure that the serverUri accept GET? Can reproduce this call using Postman?

Comment: @JonathasNascimento  Yes I can reproduce the GET request in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

basically, this happens when your server doesn't support GET and you are using that. but as mentioned you are getting it in browser GET will be working.

I noticed that you are using an HTTPS Uri, did you allow the SSL certificate for the same in your app. 
else check the below link for adding SSL.

[Does OkHttp support accepting self-signed SSL certs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103174/does-okhttp-support-accepting-self-signed-ssl-certs)

Comment: I am using the username and password for the authentication.